# Bad HCI Event : Number of Completed Packets

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, cypress, bluez, hci

I am trying to run a BLE server that transmits around 35-40KBytes/sec through notifications. I have the server and notifications up and running with BlueZ-5.54 interfacing over HCI with BT860 Laird bluetooth module that leverages CYW20704 A2 Chipset.

The problem is with HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets. From what I understand the bluetooth controller will send this event once it has transmitted buffered packets to indicate available capacity. Also it is manufacture specific and cannot be controlled.
The chipset can buffer up to 15 packets of length 251 each. I confirmed that by sending raw command using hcitool.

All good so far, here is the problem description:

1. The applications sends 15 packets to the controller
2. **After 2 x connection_interval_ms** Controller replies with HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets = 2
3. This continues until all packets are sent. At the end, controller sends 8 HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets = 2/1, all 2 x connection_interval_ms apart

I am pasting output from "btmon" here for a better understanding of the situation(the important sections are separated by /******** break-lines ******/).

From the output it is clear that the controller only transmits 2 ACL packet at a time and then waits 2xconnection_interval_ms. This really is the bottleneck of my BLE server, please let me know how I can improve it!

`I have tried` different connection intervals, mtu sizes and even different client apps(nRF connect and RaspberryPi gatt client) all give me the same results. As well as gone through documentation for BT860 and CYW20704.
Can someone please help me understand how I can fix this? Essentially,

1. Why are the packets buffered and not transmitted?
2. If they are being transmitted, why is it not reported by the controller? How do I know if this is a bug in the controller?
3. Why are "Number of Completed Packets" HCI event always 2 x connection intervals apart? How can I control its frequency?

```js
    /********************************************Initiate Connection and GATT Service discovery*****************************************/  
    > HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 19                                     #289 [hci0] 1767.983447  
          LE Connection Complete (0x01)  
            Status: Success (0x00)  
            Handle: 64  
            Role: Slave (0x01)  
            Peer address type: Random (0x01)  
            Peer address: F5:2F:BD:4D:B4:A1 (Static)  
            Connection interval: 7.50 msec (0x0006)  
            Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)  
            Supervision timeout: 4000 msec (0x0190)  
            Master clock accuracy: 0x07  
    @ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 13                           {0x0002} [hci0] 1767.983514  
            LE Address: F5:2F:BD:4D:B4:A1 (Static)  
            Flags: 0x00000000  
            Data length: 0  
    @ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 13                           {0x0001} [hci0] 1767.983514  
            LE Address: F5:2F:BD:4D:B4:A1 (Static)  
            Flags: 0x00000000  
            Data length: 0  
    < HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2              #290 [hci0] 1767.983782  
            Handle: 64  
    > HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                     #291 [hci0] 1767.985754  
          LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1  
            Status: Success (0x00)  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                   #292 [hci0] 1768.003893  
          ATT: Read By Group Type Request (0x10) len 6  
            Handle range: 0x0001-0xffff  
            Attribute group type: Primary Service (0x2800)  
    > HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                     #293 [hci0] 1768.020620  
          LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)  
            Status: Unsupported Remote Feature / Unsupported LMP Feature (0x1a)  
            Handle: 64  
            Features: 0xff 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00  
              LE Encryption  
              Connection Parameter Request Procedure  
              Extended Reject Indication  
              Slave-initiated Features Exchange  
              LE Ping  
              LE Data Packet Length Extension  
              LL Privacy  
              Extended Scanner Filter Policies  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 16                                   #294 [hci0] 1768.020769  
          LE L2CAP: Connection Parameter Update Request (0x12) ident 1 len 8  
            Min interval: 24  
            Max interval: 40  
            Slave latency: 0  
            Timeout multiplier: 400  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 18                                   #295 [hci0] 1768.034943  
          ATT: Read By Group Type Response (0x11) len 13  
            Attribute data length: 6  
            Attribute group list: 2 entries  
            Handle range: 0x0001-0x0006  
            UUID: Generic Access Profile (0x1800)  
            Handle range: 0x0007-0x000a  
            UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (0x1801)  
    > HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 11                                     #296 [hci0] 1768.043019  
          LE Data Length Change (0x07)  
            Handle: 64  
            Max TX octets: 251  
            Max TX time: 2120  
            Max RX octets: 251  
            Max RX time: 2120  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 10                                   #297 [hci0] 1768.050522  
          LE L2CAP: Connection Parameter Update Response (0x13) ident 1 len 2  
            Result: Connection Parameters accepted (0x0000)  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #298 [hci0] 1768.058490  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                   #299 [hci0] 1768.065527  
          ATT: Read By Group Type Request (0x10) len 6  
            Handle range: 0x000b-0xffff  
            Attribute group type: Primary Service (0x2800)  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 26                                   #300 [hci0] 1768.065867  
          ATT: Read By Group Type Response (0x11) len 21  
            Attribute data length: 20  
            Attribute group list: 1 entry  
            Handle range: 0x000b-0x0012  
            UUID: Vendor specific (a79ef145-bde1-4bbd-8fbd-28d5dad70a97)  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                   #301 [hci0] 1768.081234  
          ATT: Read By Group Type Request (0x10) len 6  
            Handle range: 0x0013-0xffff  
            Attribute group type: Primary Service (0x2800)  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 9                                    #302 [hci0] 1768.081687  
          ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4  
            Read By Group Type Request (0x10)  
            Handle: 0x0013  
            Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                    #303 [hci0] 1768.095555  
          ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2  
            Handle: 0x000b  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 21                                   #304 [hci0] 1768.095684  
          ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 16  
            Value: 970ad7dad528bd8fbd4be1bd45f19ea7  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #305 [hci0] 1768.096516  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 10                                     #306 [hci0] 1768.103986  
          LE Connection Update Complete (0x03)  
            Status: Success (0x00)  
            Handle: 64  
            Connection interval: 30.00 msec (0x0018)  
            Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)  
            Supervision timeout: 4000 msec (0x0190)  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                   #307 [hci0] 1768.163413  
          ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6  
            Handle range: 0x0001-0x0006  
            Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 20                                   #308 [hci0] 1768.163731  
          ATT: Read By Type Response (0x09) len 15  
            Attribute data length: 7  
            Attribute data list: 2 entries  
            Handle: 0x0002  
            Value: 820300002a  
            Handle: 0x0005  
            Value: 020600012a  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                    #309 [hci0] 1768.223048  
          ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2  
            Handle: 0x0003  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #310 [hci0] 1768.223324  
          ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 22  
            Value: 427261696e436f205261737062657272795069205374  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #311 [hci0] 1768.223995  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                    #312 [hci0] 1768.313032  
          ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2  
            Handle: 0x0006  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                    #313 [hci0] 1768.313294  
          ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 2  
            Value: 8000  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                    #314 [hci0] 1768.373681  
          ATT: Find Information Request (0x04) len 4  
            Handle range: 0x0004-0x0006  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 18                                   #315 [hci0] 1768.373818  
          ATT: Find Information Response (0x05) len 13  
            Format: UUID-16 (0x01)  
            Handle: 0x0004  
            UUID: Characteristic Extended Properties (0x2900)  
            Handle: 0x0005  
            UUID: Characteristic (0x2803)  
            Handle: 0x0006  
            UUID: Appearance (0x2a01)  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #316 [hci0] 1768.373932  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                    #317 [hci0] 1768.433025  
          ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2  
            Handle: 0x0004  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                    #318 [hci0] 1768.433350  
          ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 2  
            Value: 0100  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                    #319 [hci0] 1768.493683  
          ATT: Find Information Request (0x04) len 4  
            Handle range: 0x0007-0x0006  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 9                                    #320 [hci0] 1768.493961  
          ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4  
            Find Information Request (0x04)  
            Handle: 0x0007  
            Error: Invalid Handle (0x01)  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #321 [hci0] 1768.493965  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                    #322 [hci0] 1768.553023  
          ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2  
            Handle: 0x0003  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #323 [hci0] 1768.553275  
          ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 22  
            Value: 427261696e436f205261737062657272795069205374  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                    #324 [hci0] 1768.613688  
          ATT: Read Blob Request (0x0c) len 4  
            Handle: 0x0003  
            Offset: 0x0016  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 21                                   #325 [hci0] 1768.614021  
          ATT: Read Blob Response (0x0d) len 16  
            61 72 6b 20 47 41 54 54 20 53 65 72 76 65 72 00  ark GATT Server.  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #326 [hci0] 1768.614029  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #327 [hci0] 1768.904932  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 1  
    > HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 10                                     #328 [hci0] 1776.593921  
          LE Connection Update Complete (0x03)  
            Status: Success (0x00)  
            Handle: 64  
            Connection interval: 7.50 msec (0x0006)  
            Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)  
            Supervision timeout: 4000 msec (0x0190)  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                   #329 [hci0] 1788.592219  
          ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6  
            Handle range: 0x000b-0x0012  
            Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #330 [hci0] 1788.592438  
          ATT: Read By Type Response (0x09) len 22  
            Attribute data length: 21  
            Attribute data list: 1 entry  
            Handle: 0x000c  
            Value: 100d00072c6b8a1e1aeda86b47cec24ebcd4e8  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                   #331 [hci0] 1788.607574  
          ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6  
            Handle range: 0x000d-0x0012  
            Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #332 [hci0] 1788.607721  
          ATT: Read By Type Response (0x09) len 22  
            Attribute data length: 21  
            Attribute data list: 1 entry  
            Handle: 0x0010  
            Value: 0c110008c6a6034ef06baf8549343533924732  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 11                                   #333 [hci0] 1788.622590  
          ATT: Read By Type Request (0x08) len 6  
            Handle range: 0x0011-0x0012  
            Attribute type: Characteristic (0x2803)  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 9                                    #334 [hci0] 1788.622708  
          ATT: Error Response (0x01) len 4  
            Read By Type Request (0x08)  
            Handle: 0x0011  
            Error: Attribute Not Found (0x0a)  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #335 [hci0] 1788.623156  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                    #336 [hci0] 1788.637230  
          ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2  
            Handle: 0x000c  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 24                                   #337 [hci0] 1788.637352  
          ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 19  
            Value: 100d00072c6b8a1e1aeda86b47cec24ebcd4e8  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                    #338 [hci0] 1788.652248  
          ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2  
            Handle: 0x0010  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 24                                   #339 [hci0] 1788.652361  
          ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 19  
            Value: 0c110008c6a6034ef06baf8549343533924732  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #340 [hci0] 1788.653195  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                    #341 [hci0] 1788.697157  
          ATT: Find Information Request (0x04) len 4  
            Handle range: 0x000e-0x0012  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 18                                   #342 [hci0] 1788.697287  
          ATT: Find Information Response (0x05) len 13  
            Format: UUID-16 (0x01)  
            Handle: 0x000e  
            UUID: Characteristic User Description (0x2901)  
            Handle: 0x000f  
            UUID: Client Characteristic Configuration (0x2902)  
            Handle: 0x0010  
            UUID: Characteristic (0x2803)  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                    #343 [hci0] 1788.712242  
          ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2  
            Handle: 0x000e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 18                                   #344 [hci0] 1788.712447  
          ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 13  
            Value: 4545472052656164696e677300  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #345 [hci0] 1788.712787  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                    #346 [hci0] 1788.727224  
          ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2  
            Handle: 0x000f  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 5                                    #347 [hci0] 1788.727405  
          ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 0  
            Value:   
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #348 [hci0] 1788.749650  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                    #349 [hci0] 1788.764653  
          ATT: Find Information Request (0x04) len 4  
            Handle range: 0x0012-0x0012  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 10                                   #350 [hci0] 1788.764773  
          ATT: Find Information Response (0x05) len 5  
            Format: UUID-16 (0x01)  
            Handle: 0x0012  
            UUID: Characteristic User Description (0x2901)  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                    #351 [hci0] 1788.779703  
          ATT: Read Request (0x0a) len 2  
            Handle: 0x0012  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 18                                   #352 [hci0] 1788.779898  
          ATT: Read Response (0x0b) len 13  
            Value: 4545472052656164696e677300  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #353 [hci0] 1788.794650  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                    #354 [hci0] 1790.062100  
          ATT: Write Request (0x12) len 4  
            Handle: 0x000f  
              Data: 0100  
      
      
    /************************************************** START THE NOTIFICATIONS **********************************************************/  
    > ACL Data RX: Handle 64 flags 0x02 dlen 9                                    #354 [hci0] 1790.062100  
          ATT: Write Request (0x12) len 4  
            Handle: 0x000f  
              Data: 0100  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 5                                    #355 [hci0] 1790.062426  
          ATT: Write Response (0x13) len 0  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #356 [hci0] 1790.063602  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 54f003008bce915f8bce915f8bce915f5483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #357 [hci0] 1790.064609  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #358 [hci0] 1790.065696  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #359 [hci0] 1790.066768  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #360 [hci0] 1790.067887  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #361 [hci0] 1790.068955  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #362 [hci0] 1790.070077  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #363 [hci0] 1790.071196  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #364 [hci0] 1790.072277  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #365 [hci0] 1790.073346  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #366 [hci0] 1790.074458  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #367 [hci0] 1790.075560  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #368 [hci0] 1790.076665  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #369 [hci0] 1790.077775  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #370 [hci0] 1790.084497  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #371 [hci0] 1790.084532  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #372 [hci0] 1790.084546  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #373 [hci0] 1790.099497  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
      
    /*******************************************BREAK: SKIP TO END OF TRANSFER ************************************************/  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #493 [hci0] 1790.736984  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #494 [hci0] 1790.737022  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #495 [hci0] 1790.737037  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #496 [hci0] 1790.751975  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #497 [hci0] 1790.752012  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    < ACL Data TX: Handle 64 flags 0x00 dlen 27                                   #498 [hci0] 1790.752027  
          ATT: Handle Value Notification (0x1b) len 22  
            Handle: 0x000d  
              Data: 0000000030b6510100000000e8b651015483ac7e  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #499 [hci0] 1790.766970  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #500 [hci0] 1790.782000  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #501 [hci0] 1790.796968  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #502 [hci0] 1790.811970  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #503 [hci0] 1790.826973  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #504 [hci0] 1790.841972  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #505 [hci0] 1790.856964  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 2  
    > HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                        #506 [hci0] 1791.031954  
            Num handles: 1  
            Handle: 64  
            Count: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To get better throughput you should make use of the data length extension by setting a longer mtu and use longer notifications.

Anyway, this side runs as the "slave" role. But it's the master that controls how long the connection interval should stay open in the first place, so better check out the master setup and make sure it uses a long "connection event length". When this is equal to the connection interval you get maximum throughput.

A slave can abort a connection event earlier by stopping to listen to packets from the master. This is generally only done if the radio scheduler decides a more important radio event needs the radio right now.

Comment: I have used connection intervals of different duration as well as data length extension to get maximum LL_PDU_Size. The problem still persists that I can't transmit more than one packet per connection interval.
Is there a way to change that?